# Is there function overloading in R?

Tags: r

It is possible to overload function in R?like the `plot` function,that means two functions have the same name but different parameter list,how to achieve?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is done using "methods". See, for example, `methods("plot")` for the various `plot` `methods`.

Comment: For more advance reading check out this link: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3

Comment: @AnandaMahto You should post that as an answer -- I bet other new `useRs` will benefit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What it sounds like you're looking for are `methods`. Many common functions (`print`, `summary`, `plot`) are overloaded in R with different methods being applied depending on the `class` of the object they are being applied to.

You mentioned `plot`, but I find it easier to start by looking at `print`. One common data structure that is used in R is an object of the `class` of `data.frame`. If you look at `methods("print")`, you will find a specific print method for an object with this class. This makes it print differently from a normal `list` although a `data.frame`, is a special type of `list` in R.

Example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(lengths = 1:3, values = 1:3, blah = 1:3)
mydf ### SAME AS print(mydf)
#   lengths values blah
# 1       1      1    1
# 2       2      2    2
# 3       3      3    3

print.default(mydf) ## Override automatically calling `print.data.frame`
# $lengths
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $values
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $blah
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "data.frame"

print(unclass(mydf))  ## Similar to the above
# $lengths
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $values
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $blah
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# attr(,"row.names")
# [1] 1 2 3
```

---

You can also, of course, create your own `methods`. This might be useful when you want to print something with specialized formatting. Here's a simple example to print a vector with some unnecessary junk.

```
## Define the print method
print.SOexample1 <- function(x, ...) {
  cat("Your values:\n============", 
      format(x, width = 6), sep = "\n>>> : ")
  invisible(x)
}

## Assign the method to your object
## "print" as you normally would
A <- 1:5
class(A) <- "SOexample1"
print.SOexample1(A)
# Your values:
# ============
# >>> :      1
# >>> :      2
# >>> :      3
# >>> :      4
# >>> :      5

## Remove the "class" value to get back to where you started
print(unclass(A))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

As you can imagine, it is possible to have your `methods` do calculations in themselves. While that might seem convenient, that also ultimately leads to less "transparent" code.

Comment: It's fairly common to have print methods display values obtained with summary methods for the same class. Expereinced users would not be terribly surprised to see such behaior. Furthermore this will be obvious to those of us who reach for the code immediately.